# Cómo puedo lograr este recorte en el borde para un botón?

Tags: css

Quiero lograr este recorte para un botón aplicando css, pero no he encontrado la manera de lograrlo con exactitud. Alguien me podría ayudar por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En general lo que se hace es posicionar con position un triángulo que puede ser hecho por css mismo, este triángulo debe ser del color del fondo tras el boton y debe tener un borde en un lado para simular el borde sesgado del botón..

Comment: Tal vez encuentres aqui lo que buscas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331414/3791844) se lo que estas buscando.